# Refreshing a recyclerview in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have 2 activities: RoutineViewer and ExerciseViewer. Both activities contain fragments that are sub-classes of `ParentFragment.java`.

RoutineViewer's fragment (RoutineViewerFragment) is displaying a recyclerview. The recyclerview's data is from a static ArrayList in `ParentFragment.java`.

From RoutineViewerFragment, I can start the ExerciseViewer activity, and the fragment inside it (ExerciseViewerFragment) is used to make changes to `customRoutineExercise` in ParentFragment.java. After making the changes in ExerciseViewerFragment, I can call `requireActivity().finish()` on ExerciseViewer.java, which will take me back to RoutineViewerFragment. However, my problem is that the data in RoutineViewerFragment is not reflecting the changes I made in ExerciseViewerFragment.

Some solutions I have tried (but didn't work in this case) from looking at other similar problems:

```
// In RoutineViewerFragment onResume() with if else conditions
mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(// insert relevant position);
```

```
// In RoutineViewer.java onResume() with if else
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction.detach(currentfragment).attach(currentfragment).commit()
```

I'm guessing that the reason why `mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` isn't working is because I'm not directly passing the static `customRoutineExercise` in the constructor of mAdapter, but rather a value of the HashMap instead.

As for the `.detach().attach()`, I've read that it forces the `onCreateView()` to run again, which theoretically should refresh the recyclerview with the updated data, but it isn't.

I've left the important code segments below. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**ParentFragment.java**

```
protected static int selectedCustomRoutine;
protected static int selectedCustomExercise;
protected static ArrayList<customRoutine> customRoutineInfo = new ArrayList<>();
protected static HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<customExercise>> customRoutineExercise = new HashMap<>();
```

**RoutineViewer.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_routine_viewer);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    routineType = intent.getStringExtra("routineType");
    routinePosition = intent.getIntExtra("routinePosition", 0);

    selectedFragment = new RoutineViewerCustomFragment(routinePosition);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.routineV_fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
    break;

    }
```

**RoutineViewerFragment.java**

```
private int routinePosition;

public RoutineViewerCustomFragment(int routinePosition) {
    // constructor
    this.routinePosition = routinePosition;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_routine_viewer_custom, container, false);
    buildRecyclerView(rootView);
    return rootView;
}

// other code

private void buildRecyclerView(View rootView) {
    mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mAdapter = new RoutineViewerCustomAdapter(customRoutineExercise.get(routinePosition));

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

// Other code

private void goExerciseViewer(int position) {
     selectedCustomExercise = //number;
     selectedCustomRoutine = //number;
}
```

**ExerciseViewerFragment.java**

```
private void saveChanges() { 
 customRoutineExercise.get(selectedCustomRoutine).get(selectedCustomExercise).setSetNumber(Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString()));
 customRoutineExercise.get(selectedCustomRoutine).get(selectedCustomExercise).setRepNumber(Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Smell: `The recyclerview's data is from a static ArrayList in ParentFragment.java.`

Don't do this.

Have a repository where you store your "recycler view list" (exercises?), and have the recyclerView request (or observe if you use a ViewModel) a list.

On the fragment where you modify this list, have said fragment talk to *the same repository* either via its own viewModel or a shared one or whatever you use (search for Android ViewModels jetPack if unfamiliar).

This way, when the recyclerView comes back, it will ask for a new list (and will get the updated copy) or if observing, it will be notified that a new list is available.

The list you pass to the adapter is/should be a copy/immutable.

This is not the same but it's an Activity that has a RecyclerView and "asks" directly for the data to a repo. (This example has nothing to do with your problem, but notice how the adapter is dummy, it's just told to display the list).

https://github.com/Gryzor/CheckBoxCounter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/androidonlinux/checkboxcounter/MainActivity.kt

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the reply. I've looked up some videos about MVVM and would like to clarify a doubt in the below example.

I have a repository that is accessed by 2 different ViewModels. ViewModel 1 gets its data and is then paused() when ViewModel 2's activity is started. I edit the repository data through ViewModel 2, and call finish() on it. ViewModel 1's activity is then resumed(), but would it be able to detect the new change? The Docs say that the ViewModel is only cleared once finish() is called, but since finished is never called on activity 1, how does it detect the change?

Comment: *continued. I was using the link below as reference, and I noticed that he was using MutableLiveData in both the ViewModel and the Repository. Is that the answer to the question?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0W1QoPxfcS8

Sorry if the question is stupid, I'm still q new to the concepts of Fragments and ViewModels

Comment: hmmm I think your question is a little bit too big for a comment section but consider viewMOdels something that oulives your Activity while you're rotating the screen (for example) so you don't loose your model's "state". If the repository is updated via VM1, then there's no reason for VM2 not to pick the changes, assuming it's exposing LiveData and that you subscribe to it. Please post a more specific question or try https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210228/android-help (I'm often there, but not always, and I may take a few days to reply, work dependent) :)

Comment: I would *not* use LiveData on the Repository. I would use Co-routines and suspend functions, and let the ViewModel expose the LiveData once it has the "real" data. :)